# Using python to iterate though a file and list, starting at differen't points?

Tags: python, file-io, iteration

So I think this should be a pretty easy one.  Say I have a text file like so.

```
football
baseball
basketball
soccer
```

and a list like so for example

```
colors=["orange","white"]
```

I understand how to iterate through them together in python

```
for i,j in zip(file, colors)
```

but is there an easy way to tell the file to start on the 3rd line so that all I would get if printed is

```
basketball orange
soccer white
```

I understand how to do this with 2 lists but I'm not sure how to tell the file to start farther down.  Thanks as always, I'm still really new here and everyone is always a big help!

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
next(file) # get and discard
next(file)
for i,j in zip(file, colors):
    # do stuff
```

and then the zip operation.

If you have more than 2 or a variable number:

```
for _ in range(number_to_skip):
    next(file)
for i, j in zip(file, colors):
    # do stuff
```

This works because a file is not only iterable, but as well its own iterator. So it gives its values on its own rather than using a different iterator object (as `list` et al. would do).

Each `next(file)` gets a line from file and moves on. If you reach the "real" iteration, you are where you want to be.

Answer (score 2):

A way to do it without converting the file into a list and keeps it in its iterable state can be achieved using itertools:

```
import itertools

for i, j in itertools.izip(itertools.islice(file, 2, None), colors)
```

The `islice` will skip 2 lines without converting the file into a list and keep it in its iterable state.

`izip` is also important, since `zip` might also convert things to lists, instead of keeping them iterables.

Comment: replace 3 by 2 and you are at the user's goal :-)

Comment: +1 for islice, but I would `from itertools import izip, islice` to reduce clutter - and maybe split it over a couple of lines so the logic of the skipping is separate from the for loop

Answer (score 1):

read 2 line and don't perform any action

```
file.readline()
file.readline()
```

then use normal zip

```
for i,j in zip(file, colors):
    # perform action
```

Comment: It is not good to mix `readline()` and iteration - they use (whyever) different techniques.

Comment: @glglgl: i could not understand what you meant can you please explain

Comment: If you do `next()` first and then `readline()`, you even get a `ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data`. But I don't the other direction is really supported...

Answer (score 0):

You could do `for i,j in zip(file[2:],colors)`

Answer (score 0):

if it will fit just use readlines to get a list of lines ..

```
lines = my_file.readlines()
zip(colors,lines[3:])
```

Comment: Perhaps because it loads everything into memory. I would find it acceptable for a small file like this, but it doesn't scale. (But I don't +1 as well...)